# Subtitles position and adding math signs between figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subfig

I am working on improving my cartesian product ilustration that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to have every figure in the same size. I was trying to do this using resizebox, but I still think there is a lot to improve. The second thing is that i would like to add \times sign between figure (a) and figure (b) and = between figure (b) and figure (c). Is this possible?
Also how can I change positioning of the subtitles so that (a),(b) and (c) would be on the same level. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.08\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
            \node (2) at (0,4) {$2$};
            \draw[red] (1)--(2);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{$X_1$}
    \label{produkt_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (1) at (0,0) {a};
            \node (2) at (-1.5,1.5) {b};        
            \node (3) at (0,1.5) {c};
            \node (4) at (1.5,1.5) {d};
            \node (5) at (0,3) {e}; 
            \draw[green] (1)--(2) --(5) --cycle;
            \draw[green] (1)--(3) --(5) --cycle;
            \draw[green] (1)--(4) --(5) --cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{$X_2$}
    \label{produkt_b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (A1) at ( -2, 0) {$(1,a)$};
            \node (B3) at (1, 3) {$(2,a)$};
            \node (B4) at (-1, 3) {$(1,d)$};
            \node (B5) at ( -3, 3) {$(1,c)$};
            \node (B6) at ( -5, 3) {$(1,b)$};
            \node (C1) at ( -3, 6) {$(2,b)$};
            \node (D2) at (1,6) {$(2,d)$};
            \node (D3) at ( -1,6) {$(2,c)$};
            \node (D4) at ( -5,6) {$(1,e)$};
            \node (E1) at ( -2,9) {$(2,e)$};
            
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B6);
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B5);
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B4);
            \path[thick, green] (B6) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (B5) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (B4) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (C1) edge (B3);
            \path[thick, green] (B3) edge (D2);
            \path[thick, red] (B3) edge (D3);
            \path[thick, green] (C1) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, green] (D2) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, green] (D3) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, red] (D4) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, red] (A1) edge (B3);
            \path[thick, red] (B6) edge (D3);
            \path[thick, red] (B4) edge (C1);
            \path[thick, red] (B5) edge (D2);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{$X_1\times X_2$}
    \label{produkt_c}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document with your figure.

Comment: Where exactly should the `\times` and `=` be placed? At the same line as the subcaptions, at the vertical center of the tikzpictures or somewhere entirely different?

Comment: At the vertical center of the tikzpictures.

Comment: Aside: for the sake of the red-green colorblind, please find different colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}{0.1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \node (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
            \node (2) at (0,9) {$2$};
            \draw[red] (1)--(2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$X_1$}
    \label{produkt_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill \raisebox{7.5pt}{$\times$} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.425\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \node (1) at (0,0) {a};
            \node (2) at (-4.5,4.5) {b};        
            \node (3) at (0,4.5) {c};
            \node (4) at (4.5,4.5) {d};
            \node (5) at (0,9) {e}; 
            \draw[green] (1)--(2) --(5) --cycle;
            \draw[green] (1)--(3) --(5) --cycle;
            \draw[green] (1)--(4) --(5) --cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$X_2$}
    \label{produkt_b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill \raisebox{7.5pt}{$=$} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \node (A1) at ( -2, 0) {$(1,a)$};
            \node (B3) at (1, 3) {$(2,a)$};
            \node (B4) at (-1, 3) {$(1,d)$};
            \node (B5) at ( -3, 3) {$(1,c)$};
            \node (B6) at ( -5, 3) {$(1,b)$};
            \node (C1) at ( -3, 6) {$(2,b)$};
            \node (D2) at (1,6) {$(2,d)$};
            \node (D3) at ( -1,6) {$(2,c)$};
            \node (D4) at ( -5,6) {$(1,e)$};
            \node (E1) at ( -2,9) {$(2,e)$};
            
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B6);
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B5);
            \path[thick, green] (A1) edge (B4);
            \path[thick, green] (B6) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (B5) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (B4) edge (D4);
            \path[thick, green] (C1) edge (B3);
            \path[thick, green] (B3) edge (D2);
            \path[thick, red] (B3) edge (D3);
            \path[thick, green] (C1) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, green] (D2) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, green] (D3) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, red] (D4) edge (E1);
            \path[thick, red] (A1) edge (B3);
            \path[thick, red] (B6) edge (D3);
            \path[thick, red] (B4) edge (C1);
            \path[thick, red] (B5) edge (D2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$X_1\times X_2$}
    \label{produkt_c}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Ups, I didn't upload last version of image and code. Now is corrected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[active,floats, tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikzset{every node/.append style = {text height=2.2ex, text depth=0.5ex}}
\begin{subfigure}{0.08\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 60mm and 0mm, on grid
                        ]
\node (1)                   {$1$};
\node (2)   [above=of 1]    {$2$};
\draw[red] (1) -- (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$X_1$}
\label{produkt_a}
\end{subfigure}
\raisebox{1.7ex}{$\times$}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 30mm and 15mm, on grid
                        ]
\node (1) {a};
\node (2) [above left=of 1]     {b};
\node (3) [above=of 1]          {c};
\node (4) [above right=of 1]    {d};
\node (5) [above=of 3]          {e};
%
\draw[green] (1) -- (3) --(5)
             (1) -- (2) --(5) -- (4) -- (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$X_2$}
    \label{produkt_b}
\end{subfigure}
\raisebox{1.8ex}{$=$}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 15mm, on grid
                        ]
\node (A1)                  {$(1,a)$};
%
\node (B2) [above=of A1,xshift=-7.5mm] {$(1,c)$};
\node (B3) [above=of A1,xshift=+7.5mm] {$(1,d)$};
\node (B1) [left =of B2]       {$(1,b)$};
\node (B4) [right=of B3]       {$(2,a)$};
%
\node (C1) [above=of B1]       {$(1,e)$};
\node (C2) [above=of B2]       {$(2,b)$};
\node (C3) [above=of B3]       {$(2,c)$};
\node (C4) [above=of B4]       {$(2,d)$};
%
\node (D1) [above=of C2.south -| A1]   {$(2,e)$};
%
\draw[thick, green] 
    (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1) 
    (A1) -- (B2) -- (C1)
    (A1) -- (B3) -- (C1) 
%
    (B4) -- (C2) -- (D1)
    (B4) -- (C3) -- (D1)
    (B4) -- (C4) -- (D1);
%
\draw[thick, red] 
    (A1) -- (B4)
    (B1) -- (C3)
    (B2) -- (C4)
    (B3) -- (C2)
%
    (C1) -- (D1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$X_1\times X_2$}
    \label{produkt_c}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

rom your MWE I remove `\resizebox`. Nodes are positioned relative to each other by use of relative coordinates. Distance between are determined by use `\node distance`, which is accordingly defined at each sub figure. Math simbol between images are in `\risebox`es which enables fine tuning their vertical positioning.